# Is there another solution to WebResponse 403 error?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

There are many posts on WebResponse 403 error but my situation is a little different. I have created a console application that will run as a task on my server. The console application passes user emails in WebRequest and waits for WebResponse to receive the uri with the returning parameters. The code below worked perfectly a few days ago but one of the other programmers added a new parameter for a return web address. I know for a fact that this is causing the 403 error because if I paste the uri in IE with new parameter it works. But since I have a console application a return web address is something I cannot do, at least I don't think so.

Unfortunately the programmer said that he cannot change it back and said that there is a way to receive the uri or the entire page content and I can process it that way. I still have no clue what he was talking about because StreamReader requires a WebResponse and pretty much all other solutions I could think of.

Even though I get a 403 error the response still has the uri with the parameters I need because I can see it in IE in the web address. So all I need is the response uri. I would appreciate any help you have to offer. Below is the method giving me problems.

```
String employeeInfo = "";
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
        .Create("http://example.com/subsub.aspx?instprod=xxx&vabid=emailaddress");
    using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = 
        (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) //Error occurs here. 403 Forbidden
    {
        Uri myUri = new Uri(webResponse.ResponseUri.ToString());
        String queryParamerter = myUri.Query;
        employeeInfo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryParamerter).Get("vres");
        if (employeeInfo != "N/A")
        {
            return employeeInfo;
        }
        else
        {
            employeeInfo = "0";
            return employeeInfo;
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException)
{
    employeeInfo = "0";
    return employeeInfo;
}
```

Comment: You're saying your situation is different, but it's most likely not. 403 means that your are unauthenticated. Internet Explorer is likely passing Windows authentication or similar, which is why IE doesn't give you that error. You should be able to verify by watching the network traffic (I recommend [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)). You could also just ask the other programmer what type of authentication you need to provide.

Comment: I asked the programmer about the authentication and he said that there is no authentication that I need to provide. If I paste the uri in IE I still receive a 403 in the page body but, the response uri contains the new parameters I need.

Comment: So you're saying a 403 is entirely expected? Perhaps you should get the other programmer to return a 200 OK status code if no authentication is needed.

Comment: According to the programmer, yes. When he saw the problem I'm having, he immediately said that I'm getting the error because I'm not passing a return page for the system to return the results to. So in other words, my application is throwing the 403 error, which makes no sense to me since I'm waiting for a response.

Comment: Well that sounds ridiculous. Maybe try faking passing a return page. How does he expect you to pass a return page?

Comment: So just handle the exception thrown by the 403 error and read the response uri. It should be in the `WebException.Response` property. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx

Comment: @mason I tried passing a fake return page and I receive a 500 error. I even tried passing a page from one of my ASP .NET web applications and I received 500 error.

Comment: @JimMischel I tried your idea and it works but, it seems odd to work from the catch in the Try/Catch.

Comment: @user2632193: But that's the way you'll have to do it if the API is going to return a 403 for what used to be a valid request. The programmer's comment about an alternate way to receive the response indicates that he intended you to do it that way. It's a horribly broken API, in my opinion, but sometimes you have to work with what you're given.

Comment: @JimMischel You're right it is a horribly broken API but it works. I manage to test it on my dev server and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's follow [Jim Mischel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel) idea. We'll handle the WebException and use the Response property of the exception.

```
String employeeInfo = "";
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/subsub.aspx?instprod=xxx&vabid=emailaddress");
    using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) //Error occurs here. 403 Forbidden
    {
        Uri myUri = new Uri(webResponse.ResponseUri.ToString());
        String queryParamerter = myUri.Query;
        employeeInfo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryParamerter).Get("vres");
        if (employeeInfo != "N/A")
        {
            return employeeInfo;
        }
        else
        {
            employeeInfo = "0";
            return employeeInfo;
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    if(response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
        throw;
    }
    Uri myUri = new Uri(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
    String queryParamerter = myUri.Query;
    employeeInfo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryParamerter).Get("vres");
    if (employeeInfo != "N/A")
    {
        return employeeInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        employeeInfo = "0";
        return employeeInfo;
    }  
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking. However, you should check the status code to ensure that it's a 403. If it's anything else (a 404 or a 500, for example), you probably don't want to try processing the response.

Comment: @mason I modified the code in the catch for three exceptions that I may get 403, 404, and 500. Thanks for your help.